# Javascript Phone number validation Paratheses sign

Tags: javascript, validation

I did some searching and there where others asking this question and answers to it but none that seemed to fit what I was trying to do. Basically I'm working on a validation of the phone entry that accepts (123)4567890 as an entry. I've already implemented one that accepts a simple number string such as 1234567890 and one with dashes 123-456-7890. I know I'm making a simple mistake somewehre but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the phone number with dashes form that is working:

```
//Validates phone number with dashes. 
function isTwelveAndDashes(phone) {

    if (phone.length != 12) return false;

    var pass = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < phone.length; i++) {
        var c = phone.charAt(i);

        if (i == 3 || i == 7) {
            if (c != '-') {
                pass = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (!isDigit(c)) {
                pass = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return pass;
}​
```

and this is the one I can't manage to work out.

```
function isTwelveAndPara(phone) {
    if (phone.length != 12) return false;

    var pass = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < phone.length; i++) {
        var c = phone.charAt(i);

        if (i == 0) {
            if (c != '(') {
                pass = false;
            }
        }

        if (i == 4) {
            if (c != ')') {
                pass = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (!isDigit(c)) {
                pass = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return pass;
}​
```

Comment: Here's how to validate phone numbers: **Don't.** What if your user is overseas? What if they have an extension? The benefit you get from validation is usually washed out by closing doors you didn't mean to close. (And no validation will ensure you get a *valid* phone number; any validation rule can be fooled with a real-looking, fake number.)

Comment: To clarify this isn't being used for a commercial website, but part of my education. I'm looking to see what I'm doing wrong. I know its with the if statements on for the ( and ) characters but I'm not sure the proper syntax to join both of them into an if ( && ) statement.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. You forgot to mention that string pattern checks should be done with `regex`... +1

Comment: Ive seen this example in answer to similar questions. I don't doubt that it works (and is in fact better programming than what I'm showing) , but for the purpose of the exercise I need to stay within similar style of the isTwelveAndDashes(phone) function.

Comment: Your last else part will evaluate all the `i` values except 4. You wanna use `else if`s instead. Check my sugestion below for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it very easily with `regex`:

```
return !!phone.match(/\(\d{3}\)\d{7}/g)
```

[**Live  DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/HBYpF/)

---

**Update:**

The code you had didn't work because you forgot the `else if`:

```
    else if (i == 4) { // Added the "else" on the left.
```

Comment: What gdoron is referring to are called regular expressions. A supplement to his answer: look over Mozilla's [RegExp docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) or [try it yourself](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html).

Comment: Ive seen this example in answer to similar questions. I don't doubt that it works (and is in fact better programming than what I'm showing) , but for the purpose of the exercise I need to stay within similar style of the isTwelveAndDashes(phone) function.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something incredibly simple and dumb on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that (a RegExp rule) can make sure it matches either rule.

```
var numbers = ['(1234567890','(123)4567890','123-456-7890','1234567890','12345678901'];
var rule = /^(\(\d{3}\)\d{7}|\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}|\d{10})$/;
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    var passed = rule.test(numbers[i].replace(/\s/g,''));
    console.log(numbers[i] + '\t-->\t' + (passed ? 'passed' : 'failed'));
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
function isDigit(num) {
    return !isNaN(parseInt(num))
}
function isTwelveAndPara(phone) {
    if (phone.length != 12) return false;
    for (var i = 0; i < phone.length; i++) {
        var c = phone.charAt(i);
        if (i == 0) {
            if (c != '(') return false;
        } else if (i == 4) {
            if (c != ')') return false;
        } else if (!isDigit(c)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// or...

function isTwelveAndPara(phone) {
    if (phone.length != 12 || phone.charAt(0) != '(' || phone.charAt(4) != ')') return false;
    for (var i = 1; i < phone.length, i != 4; i++) {
        if (!isDigit(phone.charAt(i))) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Ive seen this example in answer to similar questions. I don't doubt that it works (and is in fact better programming than what I'm showing) , but for the purpose of the exercise I need to stay within similar style of the isTwelveAndDashes(phone) function.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something incredibly simple and dumb on my part.

Comment: No problem. I wrote an alternative to your function, which is much shorter, just in case…

Answer (score 0):

Checking phone number with RegEx is certainly the way to go. Here is the validation
function that ignores spaces, parentheses and dashes:

```
check_phone(num) {
   return num.replace(/[\s\-\(\)]/g,'').match(/^\+?\d{6,10}$/) != null}
```

You can vary the number of digits to accept with the range in the second regular expression `{6,10}`. Leading `+` is allowed.